# Optimize the code to get blackboard user or course by its unique run id

Tags: java, web-services, blackboard

I am fetching a course object by its course run id. Below is my code that works perfectly ok.

```
public static CourseVO getBlackboardCourseObjectByCourseRunID(String RunID){
        CourseVO[] courseVOList = null;
        try {
            courseVOList = BlackboardCoursesDAO.getAllBlackBoardCourse();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new RuntimeException("Not able to fetch blackboard courses");
        } 
        CourseVO courseVO = new CourseVO();

        int length=courseVOList.length;
        System.out.println("length : "+length);
        int i=0;
        courseVO = courseVOList[i];
        while(!courseVO.getId().equals(RunID) && i<length){
            courseVO = courseVOList[i];
            //System.out.println("in while loop ");
            i++;
        }
        return courseVO;
    }
```

But it troubles when I try to fetch this object in a loop.
If anyone can provide some better code, it will be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of getting all BlackBoard course, why not get unique BlackBoard course with RunId. Something like this >> courseVO = blackboardCoursesDAO.getBlackBoardCourseById(runId);

Comment: There is no such blackboard API to get course by its run id. It is possible for courseId which is another field in Course object.



So, I have made my custom function.

Answer (score 0):

After line 8, you can try to change lines with this>

```
Stream<CourseVO> courseList = Arrays.stream(courseVOList);

CourseVO foundCourse = courseList.filter(s -> s.getId().equals(RunID) )
  .findFirst().get();
```

Comment: It wont be much helpful as it will go inside the loop and then compare each with its run id and then return object.
I was wondering if there is any filter in the API to fetch blackboard course data as it is for courseId field that I am not familiar with.

Comment: what you need is stream.filter(). I will update my answer.